# What happens when mongodb is out of memory?

Tags: performance, memory, mongodb

For example i have db with 20 GB of data and only 2 GB ram,swap is off. Will i be able to find and insert data? How bad perfomance would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's best to google this, but many sources say that when your working set outgrows your RAM size the performance will drop significantly.

Sharding might be an interesting option, rather than adding more RAM..

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage

http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/9/13/must-see-5-steps-to-scaling-mongodb-or-any-db-in-8-minutes.html

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/12/13/mongodb-monitoring-keep-in-it-ram/

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/37f80ff39258e6f4

[Can MongoDB work when size of database larger then RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233598/can-mongodb-work-when-size-of-database-larger-then-ram)

[What does it mean to fit "working set" into RAM for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb)

You might also want to read-up on the 4square outage last year:

http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/10/15/troubles-with-sharding-what-can-we-learn-from-the-foursquare.html

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/528a94f287e9d77e

http://blog.foursquare.com/2010/10/05/so-that-was-a-bummer/

side-note:

you said "swap is off" ... ? why?   You should always have a sufficient swap space on a UNIX system!  Swap-size = 1...2-times RAM size is a good idea. Using a fast partition is a good idea. Really bad things happen if your UNIX system runs out of RAM and doesn't have Swap .. processes just die inexplicably.. that is a bad very thing! especially in production.  Disk is cheap! add a generous swap partition! :-)

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the size of your **working set**.

MongoDB can handle a very large database **and** still be very fast if your working set is less than your RAM size.

The working set is the set of documents you are working on a time and indexes.

Here is a link which might help you understand this : http://www.colinhowe.co.uk/2011/02/23/mongodb-performance-for-data-bigger-than-memor/